# In Blender 2.7 or 2.8 how can you slice off parts of a 2D grease pencil drawing and move it to its own layer?

Tags: rigging, bones, grease-pencil

Basically, I am trying to create something like this https://youtu.be/nEM_oY-RZjg. I have downloaded that file and noticed that each body part is on a separate layer. The issue is when I draw a face I never would draw a body part, create a new layer and then draw another body part. so I would like to draw my entire character first then slice it in blender to make sure the eyes, nose, mouth are on its separate layers so I can then add a parent bone and make a rig out of it. How can I do that?

[image]

If I use the 2d monkey from 2.8 as an example I would like to slice off that on its own layer so I can add bones to it to make a 2d eye rig. Unless there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

- Begin editing the GP strokes. In 2.80 you select the GP objects and go into edit mode, while in 2.79 you need to select Edit Strokes in the mode menu.
- Select the curve points that you want to move to another layer.
- Press <kbd>M</kbd> and either choose an existing layer or New Layer.